# How to spell the sound that a person makes when blowing through their mouth

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, sounds, onomatopoeia

What word should I use to indicate the sound that a person makes when blowing through their mouth (e.g they're blowing out a candle or blowing hot noodles before eating)?

Comment: English does not restrict spellings when non-linguistic sounds are being expressed. So, any way you want to. Consult some comix for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it could be opinion-based, but I offer

> I huffed out the candle.

[Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=huff&title=21st) has

> **huff**
> *verb*
> to blow or puff loudly

> **ETYMOLOGY**
> 16c: imitating the sound of blowing or puffing loudly.

Comment: I think of huff as coming from the throat with lips/mouth open not acting as a nozzle to increase or direct the flow.

Comment: @Jim that sounds like a 'grunt' to me.

Comment: I think a grunt has some vocalization in it. A huff is just air being expelled. Like A single breath/exhale from the series of breaths you’re making when you just got done running hard.

Answer (score 1):

***Sigh*** is used for the sound of blowing air out, although it has another usage as well. *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sigh)* makes the distinction clear with two senses listed for the noun *sigh* and we are referring to the second sense:

> **1** : an often involuntary act of sighing especially when expressing an emotion or feeling (such as weariness or relief) 
> **2** : the sound of gently moving or escaping air 
> // *sighs of the summer breeze*

It is even mentioned in Japanese Manga SFX (sound effects) where you would expect to see it. It is used in anime/cartoon subtitles also.

[image]

<sup>Source: [thejadednetwork.com](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/fu/)</sup>

Comment: I don't think this is a common English usage. I suspect a poor translation from Japanese.

Comment: It is not about colloquial usage though. It is a written representation of a sound used in mangas, animes, comics etc.; and it is related to one of the senses of _sigh_.